# How to Hide Label on Angular Material Button With Mat-Icon

Tags: angular-material

I have an Angular Material (5.2.2) button which displays an SVG icon. When I mouse over the button, the name of the SVG Icon is displayed like a tooltip. Can I disable this at all please?

```
<button mat-mini-fab
        color="accent"
        *ngIf="toggleR1 == 1"
        (click)="onClickR1Toggle($event)"
        style="position: absolute;"
        [style.left.px]="mapOffsetX + (1378.80 * mapScale) - 20"
        [style.top.px]="mapOffsetY + (257 *mapScale) - 20">
  <mat-icon svgIcon="points-l-up" role="img" aria-hidden="true"></mat-icon>
</button>
```

I thought that if I set the `aria-hidden` property to `true` this would do it, but evidently not.

Thanks

Comment: By tooltip, do you mean by a native tooltip like if you set the `title` attribute on an element?

Comment: I do. In the end I simply set `pointer-events: none;` on the `<mat-icon>` element, this fixed it.